# Preload Sounds in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, audio, sprite-kit, preload

I was watching a tutorial on preloading sounds in SpriteKit to avoid the delay and frame rate drop when first playing the sound.This is the way they said to use the AVAudioPlayer to preload the sounds using the `prepareToPlay()` method:

```
import AVFoundation

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    do {
        let sounds = ["sound1", "sound2"]
        for sound in sounds {
              let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(sound ofType: "mp3")!))
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        }
    }
    catch {
    }
}
```

And then playing the sound using an SKAction like this:

```
self.runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("sound1.mp3", waitForCompletetion: false)
```

How does this actually preload the sounds? Is there some reference to the actual sound file in memory when you do the `prepareToPlay()` method? It seems like I would have to use the AVAudioPlayer or the `audioPlayer` variable since that's what I used the `prepareToPlay(`) method on instead of just referencing the sound file from the SKAction.

Comment: Not sure if that is actually true, unless there is some caching going on, documentation would be needed.

Comment: To preload audio,  Just create SKAudioNodes but do not add them to the scene,  or, if you need to use SKActions,  save the action as a variable, and use the variable when needed

Comment: Shouldn't I go ahead and add the SKAudioNode to the scene once I create it? Then use the `.play()` method to use it instead of adding it to the scene and using `.play()`?

Comment: depends on how much you have going on,  If you are preloading 100 audio nodes,  you do not want all 100 on your scene

Comment: Good point. I'll plan on adding it to the scene, play the sound, then remove it from the scene once it's finished playing.

Comment: You do not have to do it like that either,  just add it to the scene when needed

Comment: Did you get this to work, @claassenApps?

Comment: @Confused, I have yet to really dig into the audio performance, but I did get this to work. What I believe is happening is the loop creating the audioPlayers creates a strong pointer to the audio file and when you preload the sound using the .prepareToPlay method, it loads the sound into memory. Since it has a strong pointer, the audio won't be removed from memory for the lifetime of the audioPlayers. Then you can play the sounds from actions because the audio is already loaded into memory. It may be redundant, but I still declare the playSoundAction as an instance variable.